# Php artisan db:seed is not working laravel 5.1.11

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am using laravel 5.1.11. I am getting the following exception error when running php artisan db:seed
[Symfon\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] class language not found

I have tried to run composer dump-autload and php artisan optimize without an success

These is my LanguageTableSeeder code

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class LanguageTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //
         Language::create( [
            'parent_id' => 'Electronincs' ,
            'language_name' => 'English' ,
            'code' => 'en' ,
            'labizale' => 'en_US.UTF-8,en_US,en-gb,english' ,
            'image' => 'gb.png' ,
            'directory' => 'image location url' ,
            'sort_order' => '1' ,

        ] );
    }
}

//Language model code

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Language extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['language_name','code','labizale', 'image','directory','sot_order'];
}


//DatabaseSeeder.php

<?php
use app\Category;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();


        $this->call(LanguageTableSeeder::class);

        Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

Where am I getting it wrong, please help

Comment: I think you'll need to use App\Artlang as by default, everything is in the App namespace in L5. Try it to see .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 5 uses [namespaces](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-directory-structure-and-namespace). You are trying to do a seed with the `Language` model but your seeder file doesn't know what `Language` class it should use for this.

You should import the `Language` class in your migration by using it at the top like:

```
use App\Language;
```

So like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Language;

class LanguageTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //
         Language::create( [
            'parent_id' => 'Electronincs' ,
            'language_name' => 'English' ,
            'code' => 'en' ,
            'labizale' => 'en_US.UTF-8,en_US,en-gb,english' ,
            'image' => 'gb.png' ,
            'directory' => 'image location url' ,
            'sort_order' => '1' ,

        ] );
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem :) Can you accept the answer so other people will see this question is answered?